# How to create light wall of letters?

Tags: after-effects

I want to create the typical light wall effect, that is often seen in music videos.
But not only the wall. I want to display text letters using those flash lights.

Probably I'm missing the right keywords as I did not find a tutorial on this yet.

I'm aiming for something similar to this template:
http://videohive.net/item/lights-flashing-3/5882600?WT.ac=item_more_thumb&WT.z_author=HK_graphic

Of course I could just buy it, but I especially want to learn while creating.

So, should I create a layer mask from text, and let eg a flashlight wall footage shine through? Or could I as well create a single flashlight (or take footage), and arrange it in a way that it will form letters?

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you mean light wall?  I'm not sure what a lightening (the thing that has bolts in the sky in a thunderstorm) wall would be.

Comment: sorry, yes I mean a wall of lights, not a thunderstorm.

Answer (score 1):

I think Trapcode Form or Particular is probably the best way to do this.  It allows you to easily set up a grid of objects (in 2D or 3D).  In this case you'd make a 2D set of objects, then mask them with your text within the plugin settings.